# Why the width of select doesn't work in IE8?

Tags: css

I put select field in my page but the rules for width doesn't apply on IE8 but works fine in firefox and chrome?
You can see the codes here: http://jsfiddle.net/48ucG/
Any help why I'm having this trouble?

Comment: how am i gonna do it, still confused on using SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was playing around with the fiddle, and adding a height to the rule seems to fix it, you will have to play with the positioning of it, but I was able to get it to appear with that width. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/48ucG/4/) Hope that helps you a bit

Comment: Thanks for your ans, i see the problem, need to set the width of the div inside li.inlin, so max-width: 100% works.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't got IE8 around to try so this is a slight shot in the dark:

Try this:

```
.width_2, width_2 option {
    width: 144px;
}
```

Making sure that the option elements as well as the select have an explicit width argument.